Power diffs: $\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathbb{E}[X^\gamma - X_*^\gamma] \leq 0 \implies \mathbb{E}[(1+ X^\gamma - X_*^\gamma)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}] \leq 1$?
I would like to show that the following implication is true for all $\gamma<1$ and $a$ in the $\mathbb{R}^d$ simplex $\Delta^d$:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathbb{E}[(a^TX)^\gamma - ({a^*}^TX)^\gamma] \leq 0 \implies \mathbb{E}[(1+ (a^TX)^\gamma - ({a^*}^TX)^\gamma)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}] \leq 1,$$
where $X$ is a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}^TX]>1$ and all entries are positive with probability $1$.
The edge cases are easy:

For $\gamma=1$, this is trivial.
In the limit $\gamma\to 0$, we interpret the LHS of the implication above as:
$$\mathbb{E}[\log(a^TX) - \log({a^*}^TX)] \leq 0$$

Then, if we take any $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and arbitrary $a \in \Delta^d$ to
see that:
$$\mathbb{E}[\log((\lambda a + (1-\lambda)a^*)^TX) - \log({a^*}^TX)] \leq 0\\
\implies \mathbb{E}\left[-\log\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}\right) - \log(1 + \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}\frac{a^TX}{{a^*}^TX})\right] \leq 0$$
Then multiplying both sides by $\tfrac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}$, and applying Fatou's Lemma we see that the inequality holds for that case as well.
I'm interested whether the inequality holds in the case $\gamma<1$.
When $\gamma <1$, $x \mapsto (1+\gamma x)^\frac{1}{\gamma}$ is concave, so the converse of the implication is trivial by Jensen's inequality.

What I tried so far:
First, letting $f_\gamma(x) = \frac{x^\gamma-1}{\gamma}$, $f^{-1}_\gamma(x) = (1+\gamma x)^\frac{1}{\gamma}$.
In that case, the implication above is equivalent to:
$$\mathbb{E}[f_\gamma(a^TX) - f_\gamma({a^*}^TX)]\leq 0 \implies \mathbb{E}[f_\gamma^{-1}(f_\gamma(a^TX) - f_\gamma({a^*}^TX))]\leq f_\gamma^{-1}(0)$$
I was trying to use the difference $\mathbb{E}[f_\gamma^{-1}(f_\gamma(a^TX) - f_\gamma({a^*}^TX))]\leq f_\gamma^{-1}(0)$ as a function of $\gamma$ to prove the implication for $\gamma \in (0, 1)$, but don't really know how to proceed.
Another approach I took was trying something like in the case $\gamma\to 0$, but I also haven't been successful so far.

Do you suppose that $\gamma > 0$? Anyway condition $\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathbb{E}[(a^TX)^\gamma - ({a^*}^TX)^\gamma] \leq 0 $  may be simplified: we may get rid of $\gamma$ in L.H.S.

$\gamma$ can be negative, but a proof for $\gamma \in (0,1)$ would be fine too.

Why do we write $\mathbb{E}[(1+ (a^TX)^\gamma - ({a^}^TX)^\gamma)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}] \leq 1 $  instead of  $\mathbb{E}( (a^TX)^\gamma
\le \mathbb{E} ({a^}^TX)^\gamma)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}} $?

Do you mean to ask whether the $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ is outside or inside the expectation? It is inside.

What if $(1+ (a^TX)^\gamma - ({a^*}^TX)^\gamma) <0$? for some value of $X$?

Good point! Let's assume that X is such that this doesn't happen, for any fixed $\gamma$. I'll add that to the question,

Minkowski's inequality gives a bound of 2, just mentioning this incase it is useful
